# Symfony 2 (Sonata admin) nested entities

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I am using the Sonata Admin bundle, but there is a problem. I'm using this code

```php
$formMapper
    ->add('shares', 'sonata_type_collection',
        array('by_reference' => false, 'label' => 'Share percent'),
        array(
            'edit' => 'inline',
            'inline' => 'table'
        )
    )
```

Here, I reference an entity so I can edit it inside of another entity. The problem is, I don't need the `inline` editing. Is there a way to just display a button "Edit shares" and not show the whole editing form?

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible.

The only way you can do this is to add a custom button to the edit view and create a route to the page you want.